# Can the font of chords be changed ("songs" package)?

Tags: fonts, color, songs

In the `songs` package, it's possible change the font of chords?
For example: Garamond font for lyrics and Computer Modern for chords?
Or change the color of chords, for example: lyrics-black, chords-red?

Answer (score 7):

By redefining  `\printchord` you can customize the font attributes for the chords. A little example using XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[chorded]{songs}

\setmainfont{Garamond}
\newcommand\lmr{\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont}    

\newindex{titleidx}{titleidx}
\noversenumbers

\renewcommand\printchord[1]{{\lmr\small\sffamily\color{red!70!black}#1}}

\begin{document}
\showindex{Complete Index of Songs}{titleidx}
\songsection{Worship Songs}

\begin{songs}{titleidx}
\beginsong{Doxology}[by={Louis Bourgeois and Thomas Ken},
                     sr={Revelation 5:13},
                     cr={Public domain.},
                     index={Praise God, from Whom all blessings flow}]
\beginverse
\[G]Praise God, \[D]from \[Em]Whom \[Bm]all \[Em]bless\[D]ings \[G]flow;
\[G]Praise Him, all \[D]crea\[Em]tures \[C]here \[G]be\[D]low;
\[Em]Praise \[D]Him \[G]a\[D]bove, \[G]ye \[C]heav'n\[D]ly \[Em]host;
\[G]Praise Fa\[Em]ther, \[D]Son, \[Am]and \[G/B G/C]Ho\[D]ly \[G]Ghost.
\[C]A\[G]men.
\endverse
\endsong
\end{songs}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using pdfLaTeX, you wouldn't load the `fontspec` package, and you will need an appropriate package providing the Garamond fonts.

Comment: This is the solution. This is that I want. {red!70!black} I think that switch to colors red and black. Is it?